# How to redirect user to another page?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, passport.js

I am stucked with one problem. As you can guess from title , problem is that i am making redirect loop . Simple situation but as a beginner i couldn't solve it . I will provide my code for you to see the problem. 
So this is my express routers `

```
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get('/auth/eventbrite',
    passport.authenticate('eventbrite', {}));

  app.get('/auth/eventbrite/callback',
    passport.authenticate('eventbrite', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
      if (!req.user) {
        throw new Error('user null');
      }
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    });

  app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session = null;
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });

  app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user, 'user');
    if (!req.user) {
      res.redirect('/');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  });
};
```

You can notice that i redirect user to /dashboard both in passport authentication and for get requests . My goal is to prevent user to come to dashboard if he/she is not authenticated .

Comment: You can't redirect your user from /dashboard to /dashboard. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I don't want to redirect from dashboard to dashboard. May be i misunderstand something , but in the last route , my goal is **if there is no authenticated user then redirect to root for login, else open the main pahe , which in this case is /dashboard ** . When i am in '/' root page (it's login page) and in the browser i enter '/dashboard' , it opens dashboard whitout checking weather i am authenticated user or not . So in that case if i am not authenticated user , i couldn't use app features. Hope now you understand my goal

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in and is redirected to the dashboard, the dashboard redirects him again to the dashboard. This creates an endless loop. Instead, if the user is logged in, the dashboard route should respond. Most probably you want to send him the dashboard html page.